# Party Mode or guest Access for Google Play Music?

Tags: google-play-music

I wonder if there is a way to use "Google Play Music" with something like a "Party Mode".
I just want to give my friends the possibility to browse and play my music library without giving them access to my entire Google Account.
They clould use the Web app with my laptop or the Android app on my MK808.

Maybe I'm using the wrong terms for searching but I coldn't find a thread with a similar problem. I can't imagine that no one else wants to do that...

Do anybody know a solution for this problem?

Comment: I doubt there is anything like that. GPlay uses DRM for articles *you've* bought, so they are licensed to you. Giving "free access" would undermine that DRM restriction.

Comment: Hmm, it's not really correct that Google Play Music is using DRM. Purchased music can be downloaded as DRM-free MP3 from Google Play Music. As for an answer: The official Google Play Music app has no such feature as Party Mode. But there are inofficial APIs for it, that may allow to build such an app. But  I am not aware that such an app exists yet.

Comment: I don't want to give free Access to other accounts
or allow to download tracks to other devices.
I'm just talking about some kind of restricted access for people at my place with physical access to my PC.
I thought of something like a Button which locks all Google Services except Google Music. If you want to unlock it again you have to provide your password.

edit:
Thanks Flow, I think this is the answer I was looking for. Unfortunately it isn't the answer I wanted to get ;)

Comment: A party mode allowing different people to play music from the Play Store on one device is something that the (now cancelled) [Nexus Q](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nexus_Q) was designed to do, so it is something that Google have thought about. Might also be worth asking whether there's any web options for this on http://webapps.stackexchange.com/

Comment: OP did so in http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/49297/party-mode-for-google-play-music

Comment: How about a simple webserver? There are several on Google Play, like `WebDAV Server`. You select a port and a folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your answers.

I found a solution for my problem.
There is a project named "[Google Musik Desktop Player](http://apps.codigobit.info/2011/10/google-music-desktop-player.html)"
That's almost what I wanted
I just let the player run on my PC and friends in my room have only access to my music library so they can choose a song or create a playlist.

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to [share songs and albums](https://support.google.com/googleplay/answer/1664444?hl=en) with friends and family. This is not quite the same as a "party mode," but is the closest thing I have found to it.

Pros: 
1. Don't need to give anyone your account information. 
2. Friends can listen to shared music on any device they want.

Cons: 
1. Only works with Google+ (for now) so your friend must have a device which can access Google+. 
2. Can listen to the entire song only once for free. 
3. Only works with limited number of songs (many more are being added though).

Setting up a type of "guest account" may be a viable option but this opens up a whole hose of security concerns - I doubt Google would implement this officially. Sharing music has a long history of abuse.

So much music can be found for free these days, sharing a listing of your favorite songs may be all that is necessary.